# Set property of a List which is also a List and from another linq query

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, linq, list

I have the sample code below. I'd like to join all children of a user. There is a one to many relationship between UserInfo and ChildInfo. I have tried this using a nested select but took a lot of time to query for huge number of data. I need to return all UserInfo with joined ChildInfo. Is there a simple linq solution on this?

```
public class UserInfo 
{
    private int _userId;
    public int UserId
    {
        get { return _userId; }
        set { _userId = value; }
    }
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }       
    private List<ChildInfo> _childInfo;
    public List<ChildInfo> ChildInfo
    {
        get { return _childInfo; }
        set { _childInfo = value; }
    }
}

public class ChildInfo
{
    private int _childId;
    public int ChildID
    {
        get { return _childId; }
        set { _childId = value; }
    }       
    private int _userId;
    public int UserId
    {
        get { return _userId; }
        set { _userId = value; }
    }
    private string _childName;
    public string ChildName
    {
        get { return _childName; }
        set { _childName = value; }
    }
}

var userList = new List<UserInfo>();      
userList = (from db in context.UserInfos                                                                        
    select new UserInfo ()
    {
        UserId = db.ID,
        Name = db.Name
    }).ToList();

var childList = new List<ChildInfo>();
childList = (from child in context.Children
          join user in userList on child.UserID equals cus.ID
          select new ChildInfo()
        {
            ChildID = db.ID,
            UserId = db.UserId,
            ChildName = db.Name    
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: Just remove `.ToList()` from first query. Or use @Stanley solution

Comment: Are you using EF? If yes, aren't the UserInfo and ChildInfo entites related?

Comment: I am not using EF. Also addtl info, there is a one to many relationship between UserInfo and ChildInfo.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to join the tables directly instead of the hydrated results:

```
from child in context.Children
join user in context.UserInfos 
    on child.userID equals user.ID
select new ChildInfo()
    {
        ChildID = child.ID,
        UserId = user.ID,
        ChildName = child.Name    
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: Can't do this. There is a one to many relationship. So i've tried nested select and the performance was not good.

Comment: Does it not work or is it just slow?  Also it would help to add the data structure to your question so we could see how the tables relate.

Answer (score 0):

Your current queries would execute twice on the database, once for getting a user list and later to get the ChildInfo instead you may execute one query with a join like:

```
childList = (from child in context.Children
          join user in context.UserInfos on child.ID equals user.ID
          select new ChildInfo()
        {
            ChildID = db.ID,
            UserId = db.UserId,
            ChildName = db.Name    
        }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see in your query, all the rows in the last result have `Child.ID = User.ID` because of the `join condition`. But you still want to select both `Child.ID` and `User.ID`? In fact your query equals to this one:

```
var childList = from child in context.Children
                where context.UserInfos.Any(x=>x.ID == child.ID)
                select new ChildInfo(){
                           ChildID = child.ID,
                           UserID = child.ID,
                           ChildName = child.Name
                       };
```

Comment: @Liz your query even doesn't compile, you used arbitrary names in your query. I don't see any change since your edit. What is this `child.UserID equals cus.ID`? what is `cus`? I guess it's `user`, if so that `join condition` makes your `select` a little ridiculous when you select both `child.ID` and `user.ID` which are the same.

Answer (score 0):

I belive what you want is:

```
userList = (from user in context.UserInfos                                                                        
select new UserInfo ()
{
    UserId = user.ID,
    Name = user.Name
    ChildInfo = (from child in context.ChildInfo where child.UserId == user.Id select
    new ChildInfo
    {
        ChildID = child.ID,
        UserId = user.Id,
        Name = child.Name
    }).ToList()
}).ToList();
```

If that is to slow chances are you are missing an index on the `UserId` column.